# Calling SetRefreshing(false) outside main thread is not allowed. Workaround?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-layout

In my android app, I want to refresh my ListView using a SwipeRefreshLayout, and inside the onRefresh() method I want to create a new thread for this task. Since my refresh method has to fetch a bunch of files, it will freeze the app temporarily when called from the main thread, which ruins the whole purpose of using a SwipeRefrehLayout (to inform the user when the app is refreshing, and when it has finished doing so).

The last part is what I'm having trouble with. I want to call SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false) to stop the refresh anmimation after I fetch the files. The way I'm doing this is by calling setRefreshing at the end of the same refresh method inside the new thread, but the problem is I get an error saying

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I'm thinking if there's a way to create a thread end listener, that would be the best way of doing so, but unfortunately I've researched this for a couple of weeks with no solution.

Is there an obvious alternative that everyone uses with the SwipeRefreshLayout? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's some code in case my explanations were terrible (that would be understandable)

```
            public void onRefresh() {

                // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.

                //I used refreshLayout.getContext() instead of the "this" keyword since "this" would return an OnRefreshListener instead of my actual context
                //I pass my refreshLayout to the constructor so it knows which to stop animating at the end.
                Thread thread = new Thread (new Refresher(refreshLayout.getContext(), refreshLayout));
                thread.start();

                //I use this to update the adapter in my ListView after it has been refreshed by my Refresher thread.
                if (listView != null)
                    listView.setAdapter(new CategoryListAdapter(Categories, refreshLayout.getContext()));
            }
```

my Refresher class:
`

```
public class Refresher implements Runnable {

    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    Context context;

    public Refresher (Context c, SwipeRefreshLayout rl) {

        refreshLayout = rl;
        context = c;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //Call the method that fetches the files.
        ((CategoryMenu) context).RefreshCategories(CategoryMenu.SaveDirectory);

        //Here's where my error gets thrown.
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        //I understand why, but I don't know a good workaround.

    }

}
```

`

Comment: Use an AsyncTask

Comment: @Denny This worked perfectly! Could you add this as an answer so that I can set this question as solved?

Comment: Sure, I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the UI smooth you can use an AsyncTask, it will perform actions on the background, you can get progress updates and get notified when the task is done. 
Example from the [android dev site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        long totalSize = 0;
        // do some long running operation on the background
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
            // Escape early if cancel() is called
            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }
        // pass the result to onPostExecute()
        return totalSize;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        // update the UI when you're done
        showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
```

Try with runOnUiThread, hope this solves your issue

Comment: Unfortunately, this still made the app freeze when refreshing. @Denny had the right answer which is to use an AsyncTask, but it's a comment so I cannot set it as solved :( I still added a vote since you made me learn some good tips such as using ActivityClass.this to get the context from inside an onClickListener for example :)